# Retrieve a list of specific elements from an XDocument using LINQ

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have tried following tutorials about retrieving particular elements from an XDocument using LINQ, but so far every time I attempt, I am shown a message that the search yielded no results.
Here is what I have at the moment (I'm trying to make a list of all the "Widgets" found in the XDoc:

```
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(itemHtml);

    var widgets = from XElement x in xdoc.Descendants("Widgets")
        select x;
```

"itemHtml" is in String format.

Here's my XDoc

```
<PageData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="PB">
  <IsMasterLayout>false</IsMasterLayout>
  <masterID>0</masterID>
  <pageID>32</pageID>
  <languageID>1033</languageID>
  <title>TestPage</title>
  <Zones>
    <DropZoneData>
      <DropZoneID>DropZone1</DropZoneID>
      <isMasterZone>false</isMasterZone>
      <Columns>
        <ColumnData>
          <Guid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Guid>
          <Display>true</Display>
          <columnID>0</columnID>
          <width>35</width>
          <CssClass />
          <CssFramework />
          <unit>percent</unit>
        </ColumnData>
        <ColumnData>
          <Guid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Guid>
          <Display>true</Display>
          <columnID>1</columnID>
          <width>65</width>
          <CssClass />
          <CssFramework />
          <unit>percent</unit>
        </ColumnData>
      </Columns>
    </DropZoneData>
  </Zones>
  <Widgets>
    <WidgetData>
      <ID xmlns="PW">23</ID>
      <ControlURL xmlns="PW">ContentBlock.ascx</ControlURL>
      <ColumnID xmlns="PW">1</ColumnID>
      <Order xmlns="PW">0</Order>
      <Minimized xmlns="PW">false</Minimized>
      <DropID>DropZone1</DropID>
      <ColumnGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ColumnGuid>
      <ChildColumns />
      <KeyValues />
      <Associations>
        <ObjectData>
          <ObjectId>33</ObjectId>
          <ObjectType>Content</ObjectType>
          <ObjectLanguage>1033</ObjectLanguage>
        </ObjectData>
      </Associations>
    </WidgetData>
    <WidgetData>
      <ID xmlns="PW">32</ID>
      <ControlURL xmlns="PW">ListSummary.ascx</ControlURL>
      <ColumnID xmlns="PW">0</ColumnID>
      <Order xmlns="PW">0</Order>
      <Minimized xmlns="PW">false</Minimized>
      <DropID>DropZone1</DropID>
      <ColumnGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ColumnGuid>
      <ChildColumns />
      <KeyValues />
      <Associations />
    </WidgetData>
  </Widgets>
</PageData>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have default [xml namespace](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) defined `xmlns="PB"`. Thus you need to use it when querying elements, because `Widgets` is only local name of element - full name will be `{PB}Widgets`:

```
XNamespace ns = "PB";
```

Or you can get default namespace of root:

```
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

And then use it to provide element name:

```
var widgets = from w in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Widgets")
              select w;
```

Or simply

```
var widgets = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Widgets");
```